# Not sure what i'm looking for (matrix, db-like structure) to organize files by tags

Tags: c++, c++11

i was messing around organizing my music files when i asked myself why windows nor linux offer a way to organize a folder by custom tags in a database-likle manner rather than hierarchically.

The problem i wanted to solve is the following:
I have music files

A titled "tempest" from Beethoven, classical music in a piano only version.

B titled "whatever" from Mozart, classical music orchestral

D titled "one winged angel" from Uematsu, classical style, game ost, orchestral

C titled "one winged angel" same as before, violin only, cover from Taylor Davis.

And whatever "main" information i use for grouping, makes listing files by any other category immpossible.
Hence i whished to save files in an hidden folder with a simple increasing number.format, and have a program in which i can add files, add categories, search by tags, and end up with a list of the files i want. E.g. today i want to listen to all piano only pieces independently of their composer-time period.

I started making a structure of vectors containing vectors (aka matrix) but indexing lines and column by string started getting complicated when i want to remove a column. 
And searching files by tag would require me to have each tag as an object knowing all files that use it, and it starts becomming more similar to a 3d matrix.
I though it would be better to think of this as a database, started with sqllite but ended with the problem of being unable to remove columns (i know i can create a copy etcc, but i wanted to avoid messy workarounds).
Also an sql-like database wouldn't allow me to have an area dedicated to a list of random tags for each file without a definite category.

Is there any existing library that rather then working as an sql database offers me something similar to a search/insert optimized matrix for strings? I don't think i was the first one thinking about that, someone must have done something similar.

[This](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/tag-explorer/9nblggh67ngr?activetab=pivot:overviewtab#) is very similar to what i want to achieve (strictly speaking about functionality), but rather than having only a bunch of random tags, i'd like to have some categories AND a set of random tags. 
The problem with random tags only is you can't use the same word when it refers to different things. For example if the title of a piece is A and there's a film named A with a piece titled B, filtering A in the mess of tags would give both, while with categories i could filter pieces titled A. But the random mess of additional tags without category is useful too, for information you don't want to fill in most of the files and that would take pointless space in a standard database.

Comment: Apple users have had such a thing for years https://github.com/jdberry/tag/ because ordering files in a hierarchy isn't always best - where do you file an invoice for customer X in year 2014? Under `/invoices`? Under `/customer X`? Under `/2014`? With tags you can find that file wherever it is. Linux users can use `xattr` command. You could use an alternate stream on NTFS but many utilities and FAT disks will lose them all for you in an instant - without warning.

Comment: @MarkSetchell i updated the question; there's a similar app for windows, but in the last paragraph of the question you can see why i don't want to limit my program to uncategorized tags. Anyway thanks for the response!

Comment: _i asked myself why windows nor linux offer a way to organize a folder by custom tags_ AFAIK Windows _can_ organize photos by tags. Though I've never used it by myself I saw it on the desktop of my father. I found this link [Apply tags to pictures with windows 10](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store/apply-tags-to-pictures-with-windows-10/2874e835-b0c6-4f41-a12d-7673048910f8). I would wonder if there were nothing similar for sound files.

Comment: @Scheff i defined in my last paragraph the requirements, which windows does not meet.

Comment: Asking for existing libraries is off-topic. And if you want to implement that yourself, your question is way too broad.

Comment: @chtz of course it looks broad compared to a question that asks about a specific data structure's lookup complexity, because the question goes back to the root to which data structure or mix of data structures someone with more experience than me would use in a similar context. You can find plenty of sources about hyerarchical file systems, tag-based file systems, but very little about graph file systems and i found nothing about categorized tags, which is what i'm trying to do.